# Date Label is not in sequence as date Problem on X axis in r

Tags: r, plot

I have data from `01-January-2015 to 12-05-2015` and I have plotted the data very well. But the Date label on `x-axis` is not correctly labelled. Either it is labelled on alphabetic sequence or in integer sequence. Output Picture is attached herewith

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: Likely your data in the date column is not in a datetime format. If you convert it and sort by date, you will have a real time series chart. You should include code and a sample of the data (use `dput` to push out a sample) so that people can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `class()` function to determine whether the date variable is stored as a character. If it is, then convert it using `as.Date()` or `as.POSIXct()`, as in the example below:

```
dateVariable <- '01-January-2015'
class(dateVariable)
"character"

dateVariable  <- as.Date(dateVariable, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Once the variable is converted, it should plot properly.